# What's a specific word for a programmer who has contextual knowledge of a particular programming language, framework, environment, etc?

Tags: programming

This term was used by an old Senior Developer of mine but for the life of me I can't recall it. The context of the conversation was that he wasn't necessarily more *skilled* than an Intermediate Developer, but he had more *knowledge* and *experience* in particular areas. In a sentence, it would be used like, `I have more _____.`

My brain keeps giving me the terms `region knowledge` and `area knowledge`, and I feel like those may be *close*, but are definitely not it.

Comment: "domain knowledge", perhaps?

Comment: @Hellion Looks like we answered at the same time

Comment: *Subject matter expertise*? Commonly abbreviated *SME*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have more domain knowledge.

Can refer to more knowledge of either the technical environment or the 'business side'.

Comment: Domain knowledge was indeed the term I was looking for! And shoutouts to Hellion for also answering it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the words **practiced**, **seasoned** or **adept** could be what you're looking for. Example usage:

> He is more practiced in this field of programming.
>
> She is as an adept in functional programming.
>
> He is a seasoned web-developer.

It's used differently than "domain knowledge" or "region knowledge" is but I think it can still be relevant to your question.